# Getting Errors when trying to log Server Chat info in on_message [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I'm making a server bot, and I'm trying to make the bot log user messages when they send a file.

```py
...
with open("messages.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(f'{message.author.name}: "{message.content}" {time.strftime("%H:%I:%M")} {message.guild.name}\n')
...
```

Its somewhat working for some users, but I keep getting errors when others send messages. "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2615' in position 0: character maps to " And sometimes it will just clear the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use unicode to parse non-ascii strings. (`'\u2615'` is decoded as ☕ in UTF-8)

```
open("messages.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')
```